# Sleep , freeze, end?

Tags: javascript, sleep, break

could you please help me how to fix this? I want to send just one command, but to be as accurate as possible (on milliseconds).
This is the part I need to fix:

```js
document.getElementById("arrTime").onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(attInterval);
    let time = document.getElementsByClassName("relative_time")[0].textContent.slice(-8);
    input = prompt("Set Arrival Time", time);
    inputMs = parseInt(prompt("Set the milliseconds", "500"));
    delay = parseInt(delayTime) + parseInt(inputMs);
    let arrivalTime;
    arrInterval = setInterval(function () {
        arrivalTime = document.getElementsByClassName("relative_time")[0].textContent;
        if (arrivalTime.slice(-8) >= input) {
            setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("troop_confirm_submit").click(); }, delay);
        }
    }, 5);
    document.getElementById("showArrTime").innerHTML = input + ":" + inputMs.toString().padStart(3, "0");
    document.getElementById("showSendTime").innerHTML = "";
};
```

Now, there is an "if statement" to perform action at **arrivalTime.slice(-8) >= input** (so for example 19:24:30), but it is sending requests every 5ms. So over that one second time, it sends 200 requests to the server.
I don´t want to change those 5ms, as I need to have it as accurate as possible, but I want to break the script, freeze it or sleep it for 1 second once the command is performed. So something like: setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("troop_confirm_submit").click(); **Sleep 1 second** }, delay);

Anyone who can help, please?

Comment: be aware that `if (arrivalTime.slice(-8) >= input) {` is comparing 2 strings rather than numbers

Comment: Also is `clearInterval(attInterval)` supposed to be `clearInterval(arrInterval)`?

Comment: also note that if you're already writing your JS in its own file, there is no reason to use the legacy `onclick` attribute. As an old "JS mirror" of the HTML element attribute, It has no place in modern JS. Use `.addEventListener("click", ...)` instead.

Comment: Hi, I know. It should perform the command at a specific time, so once the arrivalTime.slice(-8) is f.e. 19:30:00. But the problem is, that **19:30:00** lasts for one second, so the string is up for 1 second and the refresh is every 5 ms. So for that one second time, it sends 200 requests.  And yes, it should be clearInterval(attInterval). It´s for another function, can be ignored in this situation

Comment: If you rely on clock time: don't check for click time, check for "what time was it last time I checked, what time is it now, and how many seconds since the time I actually care about has it already been". When your JS doesn't run in-focus, its timers are heavily deprioritised in modern browsers, and it can be as long as 30 seconds between intervals, _irrespective of what you had set it to_. Timeouts are _only_ guaranteed to be _at least_ as long as you requested, but there is no guarantee they will fire even anywhere close to that.

Comment: Thank you, Mike, but I want to insert the time to the script, so it clicks the button at the time I insert it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise to break up the functions as to manage the interval a little easier

```js
document.getElementById("arrTime").onclick = function() {
  clearInterval(attInterval);
  let time = document.getElementsByClassName("relative_time")[0].textContent.slice(-8);
  input = prompt("Set Arrival Time", time);
  inputMs = parseInt(prompt("Set the milliseconds", "500"));
  delay = parseInt(delayTime) + parseInt(inputMs);
  startInterval(input, delay)
  document.getElementById("showArrTime").innerHTML = input + ":" + inputMs.toString().padStart(3, "0");
  document.getElementById("showSendTime").innerHTML = "";
};

function startInterval(input, delay) {
  arrInterval = setInterval(function() {
    let arrivalTime = document.querySelector(".relative_time").innerText;
    if (+arrivalTime.slice(-8) >= +input) {
      clearInterval(arrInterval); // pause the interval
      setTimeout(() => {
        startInterval(input, delay)
      }, 1000 * 60); // restart the interval in 1 minute       
      setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector("#troop_confirm_submit").click();
      }, delay);
    }
  }, 5);
}
```

Comment: This is not doing what I need. When I use it, input some time, f.e. 21:05:00, and ms 500, it doesn´t perform **document.querySelector("#troop_confirm_submit").click()**, event that arrivalTime.slice(-8) >= input

Comment: ```
document.getElementById("arrTime").onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(attInterval);
    let time = document.getElementsByClassName("relative_time")[0].textContent.slice(-8);
    input = prompt("Please enter desired arrival time", time);
    inputMs = parseInt(prompt("Please enter approximate milliseconds", "500"));
    delay = parseInt(delayTime) + parseInt(inputMs);
    document.getElementById("showArrTime").innerHTML = input + ":" + inputMs.toString().padStart(3, "0");
    document.getElementById("showSendTime").innerHTML = "";
    setArrivalTime();
};
```

Comment: function setArrivalTime() {
    let arrivalTime;
    arrInterval = setInterval(function () {
        arrivalTime = document.getElementsByClassName("relative_time")[0].textContent;
        if (arrivalTime.slice(-8) >= input) {
            setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("troop_confirm_submit").click(); }, delay);
        }
    }, 5);
}

Comment: I have it split on 2 functions, everything is working as it should be, just not performing only 1 command

Comment: but 200 as it is doing the commands every 5 ms for 1 second

Comment: and my goal is to stop it once the first request is performed

Comment: So when I input any time it clicks the button at the exact time as I input it